# add uri parameter to Route name in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, crud

I'm working on a Laravel project, and I made a simple CRUD system, but I have a small problem

to generate the URL system in my project, I made a `Route::macro` 
and add it to `AppServiceProvider`:

```
Route::macro('crud', function () {
        Route::group([

         ], function () {

            //    Route::resource('', 'CrudController');
            Route::get('{model}', 'CrudController@index');
            Route::get('{model}/create', 'CrudController@create');

            Route::post('{model}', 'CrudController@store');             /** << post **/

            Route::get('{model}/{id}', 'CrudController@show');
            Route::get('{model}/{id}/edit', 'CrudController@edit');

            Route::match(['PUT', 'PATCH'],'{model}/{id}', 'CrudController@update'); /** << post **/
            Route::delete('{model}/{id}', 'CrudController@destroy'); /** << post **/
        });
    });
```

this works great so far, but the issue is I need to use `->name()` with it, and adding the `$model` parameter to it!

#### example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Route::get('{model}', 'CrudController@index')->name('{model}.index');
```

is it possible?, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all models names and loop through them and add the model name to the route name prefix at runtime

```
loop (model in models) 
   Route::get("{model}","Atcion")->name("{model}.index")
endloop
```

I hope my answare helps you in your project

Comment: Actually this is a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

Here in this example you can loop over of some numbers and dynamically create some routes:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
     Route::get('test/' . $i, 'Controller@test_' . $i)->name('test.' . $i);
 }
```

You can check that all added routes with "php artisan route:list".
I don't recommend you to do that, but for your case you can somewhere in routes.php define array like this, and loop over on that:

```
 $models = ['user', 'owner', 'admin'];
 foreach ($models as $model) {
     Route::get($model, 'CrudController@index')->name($model . '.index');
 }
```

Or you can define that array in configs (for example in "config/app.php") like:

```
 'models' => ['user', 'owner', 'admin'];
```

And in routes.php you can just retrieve that with this (don't forget to run "php artisan config:cache" after changing app.php):

```
 $models = config('app.models');
 // foreach loop
```